# How to read an API response with moviepy directly as a video

Tags: python, mp4, moviepy

Hi I am trying to add a fade-in effecto to a video that comes generated by an api. For this I need to use the python library moviepy. My first approach is saving the API response request as an mp4 file and afterwards read the file with moviepy again to add the fade in effect and save it again.

```
from moviepy.editor import *
from moviepy.video.fx.all import fadein

response = resquests.post(url, json=payload, headers=headers)

with open("response1.mp4"."wb") as f:
    f.write(response.content)

clip = VideoFileClip("response1.mp4")
clip = cip.fadein(duration=1)
clip.write_videofile("response2.mp4")
```

Is there any way to generate "response2.mp4" directly, skipping the step of generating "response1.mp4" as a file before?

Answer (score 2):

I think with `moviepy` the answer is **No**. The `VideoFileClip` class internally uses [`ffmpeg` external command to read/process the video which requires the actual file(name in the disk) to run](https://github.com/Zulko/moviepy/blob/b5bb086439cfd0960011a065f229eb7a7b4ebad5/moviepy/video/io/ffmpeg_reader.py#L793)